# ENEEDAUTH on upgrade to node 16 and accessing private repo of my company

Tags: node.js, angular, artifactory

I have upgraded to Node 16 and updated mu npmrc file to access the private artifactroy of my firm.

In old version i.e node 14 when I have same changes in npmrc and I do `npm whoami` i get my username

my `.npmrc` file looks like this

```
%scope%:registry=%artifactoryurl%
%artifactoryurl%:_auth=%auth_token%
%artifactoryurl%:always-auth=true
```

But when I update to node 16 I get error as

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

Note: Upgrade to Node 16 and access to repo This works in MAC but I face this issue in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are encountering the issue that is reported here.
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2453
Since you are accessing private Artifactory, you would need to add the user.

Comment: When I use add user and mention my username which is email id it say "Name may not contain non-url-safe chars"